# How to move form one view controller to other based on success and failure status using segues in IOS

Tags: uistoryboardsegue

So here is what i am doing.. I have loginviewcontroller and inboxviewcontroller, i connected my inboxviewcontroller through segue attached to my login button in loginviewcontroller, i need to navigate to inbox view controller only on success status, if login fails i need to show an alert and  stay in loginviewcontroller, i checked with prepareforSegue method and played around it, but it seems like its not going to help me as segue will open inboxviewcontroller irrespective of wether perpareforsegue is called or not. I don't want to write IBaction for login button and then  called 
"[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];" inside it. 
This scenario pops up 2 question in my mind
1) Is perpareforsegue method is used only to pass data from one to another view controller and can't be used for other purpose (like validation) ?
2) Do i need to follow other mechanism to validate, and is it not possible to validate with what i am heading with?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't like this kind of approach, I think segues should be intended as "synchronous-like operations", meaning that once they are triggered (manually or automatically as in your scenario) they should immediatly "perform". 
They are UI related, not Model related (I'd intend an asynchronous login as something I would write in a Model part of my MVC architecture).

However, you could try the following

1) leave your storyboard segue as is (from button to next view controller) but assign an identifier to it ("segue1")

2) in your login view controller, declare a "isLogged" property and put a shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender: override like this

```
- (BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString*) identifier sender:(id) sender {
   if (!self.isLogged) { 
       [self login]; //your login method
      }
   return self.isLogged;
}
```

3) at the end of your login method, when login is successful, write this

```
self.isLogged = YES;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];
```

In this way, when login button is clicked for the first time, it should trigger the login method instead of performing the segue. At the end of the login process, it should manually trigger the segue by id.